# How to limit possible arm recommendations to a subset of items?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have the following scenario:

There is a universe of items to recommend [i1....iN] where N is quite large (say 1 million).
There are categories [c1...cK]. Each category consists of a subset of the items.

The user can go to pages which display items from a given category.

I would like to display recommended items for each category page to a user using a single bandits model across all category pages. So when I ask for a set of top-K recommendations ("actions") for category page ci, the results should be limited to the set of items available within ci.

Is there a way to do this with Vowpal Wabbit?

Answer (score 2):

When you ask VW for a contextual bandit prediction using the ADF (action dependent features) form allows you to specify which actions can be chosen on for that prediction. The ADF form can be read about more [here](https://vowpalwabbit.org/docs/vowpal_wabbit/python/latest/tutorials/python_Contextual_bandits_and_Vowpal_Wabbit.html#contextual-bandit-algorithms-and-input-formats), and contrasted with the more common standard contextual bandit. This would allow you only ask for predictions of actions in the category you're currently looking at. This works because actions are defined as the set of the features that compose them, and so you can present any set of features per action for each prediction. This means that changing the actions between calls is not an issue.

However, empirically we see using contextual bandits with > ~100 actions to not be very effective. Essentially the very small exploration probabilities does not work well with the update rule.

So, it's doable but I am not sure how effective it will be.

In a situation such as this a common approach is to use another model to get a pool of recommendations and then use a contextual bandit as an L2 ranker to personalize a pool of 50 or so actions that were suggested.